# The graph of inversely proportional relationships

Tags: graph-theory, physics

If y is inversely proportional to x, the graph of y against 1/x is a straight line through the origin.
What i don't understand is as the line passes the origin, the value of y is 0, then the value of 1/x is also 0, then what is the value of x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote that "the graph of $y$ against $\frac{1}{x}$ is a straight line through the origin." That is not correct. The graph of $y$ against $\frac{1}{x}$ is indeed straight, but it doesn't include the origin point $(0, 0)$. So the premise of the question is wrong and the trouble you are concerned about doesn't arise.

Comment: Thank you, i understand up to this, there's one graph i saw where the line extends until it just touches the origin, so is the graph wrong? Or do we just show it to touch the origin but we don't actually take it as touching (0, 0)

Comment: The graph is probably rendered in an imprecise way; it should not include (0, 0). Perhaps it would be best if the line were drawn with a small open circle at the origin.

Answer (score 0):

$y$ is said to be inversely proportional to $x$ if whenever $$y = \frac{k}{x} \qquad \text{for all } x \neq 0$$ where $k$ is a constant.

I think the issue you are encountering is that when $x = 0$, the above is undefined. For example, when $k = 1$, we have

[image: k/x]